# Throwing errors/response outside exports.handler

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've just started using AWS Lambda/Node.JS/API Gateway with API Lambda Proxy integration, and I'm struggling with something that should be simple. Handling error from outside *exports.handler*.

I've developed all my code, it's all working fine, however, I'm struggling to handle errors. I'm using *async/await*, no callback.

Basically, my code looks like something like this:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const sampleVar = await sampleFunction();

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(sampleVar),
    isBase64Encoded: false
  };
  return response;
}
```

Great, right? My problem is that all my "real code" is being developed outside the exports.handler in different functions, something like:

```
async function sampleFunction() {
  const test = 123;
  return anotherFunction(test);
}

async function anotherFunction() {
  const test2 = 'blablabla';
  return test2;
}
```

Now, let's suppose that an error happens on my sampleFunction and I need to throw the error right away. I could just go `throw { statusCode: 400, etc, etc };`, however, if I throw the error, I get a "*500 Internal Server Error*" as my response, no matter what. I can only proper break my code if I handle the error from within my exports.handler function. In that case, I could go `return { statusCode: 400, etc, etc };` or `context.fail()`, etc, and everything would be alright.

My question is: is there any way to "break" my code and send a proper response from outside my *exports.handler*? Or maybe externally call my *exports.handler* to return a specific response?

Comment: dumb question, maybe....did you check the box "Use Lambda Proxy integration". if you didnt, then setting the statusCode within Lambda wont matter...rather you would have to handle that response via integration response and do a lambda regex lookup

Comment: Yes, I have checked the box. The problem is that I can't just throw a proper error and stop my code from outside my exports.handler. I'm probably struggling with how to send a "global" response that will stop my code and return a proper response. If I use "throw" the code stops with 500 Internal Server.

Comment: so, the reason is because a proper response is the object you specified (ie `{statusCode: 4xx, etc etc}`, a throw will return an error, having props message, stackTrace etc etc. This isnt what api gateway likes, so you are getting a malformed response most likely. your handler needs to format the response...inferring your handler needs to catch any throws and format a response accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, i would write this in the comments, but the markup is a bit poor. I would do something like the below:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  return await sampleFunction().then(craftOk).catch(craftErr);
}

function craftOk(res) {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(res),
    isBase64Encoded: false
  };
}

function craftBad(err) {
  return {
    statusCode: 400,
    body: err.message,
    isBase64Encoded: false
  }
}
```

for fun, I wrote a test script to validate return from catch on async/await...maybe it will help

```
function test(toggle) {
    return (toggle) ? Promise.resolve("yay") : Promise.reject(new Error("boo"))
}

async function main1() {
    let res =  await test(true).then( res => {
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: res,
            isBase64Encoded: false            
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return {
            statusCode: 400,
            body: err.message,
            isBase64Encoded: false            
        }
    })
    return res
}

async function main2() {
    let res =  await test(false).then( res => {
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: res,
            isBase64Encoded: false            
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return {
            statusCode: 400,
            body: err.message,
            isBase64Encoded: false            
        }
    })
    return res
}

main1().then(console.log)
main2().then(console.log)
```

Comment: I got it now! My mistake was to forget to catch those errors after throwing them. Many thanks! Helped a lot!